# Data initialization on reset in lpc2468

Tags: arm

i am working on arm controller

> **lpc2468**

. previously i worked upon

> lpc2148

.IN lpc2148 for variables i dont want to be initialized i used **#Pragma NOINIT**.But when i used the same in lpc2468 the **data under Noinit section is initialized**.i am using **keil uvision 4**. what should i do so that the variables in the noinit section are not initialized.

My program size is the following

**Program Size: Code=141188 RO-data=18972 RW-data=2328 ZI-data=30800**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved above Problem by placing

## Pragma arm section zidata = "NOINIT"